# Stopping a function from triggering without breaking the other functions

Tags: javascript

tl;dr I wanted to calculate a discount and then for the function to return me the final value. Currently it returns me the correct values, except if my "Deadline (months)" input field is empty it defaults to 20% same happens if it's 0, how can I make it so whenever that field is 0 / empty it get's skipped / not trigger ? for testing if you want to https://jsfiddle.net/zwoutfyp/

```
//Dropdown list calculation//
var service_prices = new Array();
service_prices["0"] = 0;
service_prices["1500"] = 1500;
service_prices["4000"] = 4000;
service_prices["8000"] = 8000;

//^gives me value of each drop down list item
function getServicePrice() {
  var serviceOptionPrice = 0;
  var form = document.forms["formulario"];
  var selectedOption = form.querySelector("#servicePrice");
  if (service_prices[selectedOption.value]) {
    serviceOptionPrice = service_prices[selectedOption.value];
  }
  return serviceOptionPrice;
}


//checkbox calculation//

function extraPrices() {
  var extraPrices = 0;
  var form = document.forms["formulario"];
  var selectedBoxes = form.querySelectorAll("#selectedBox");
  selectedBoxes.forEach(box => {
    if (box.checked == true) {
      extraPrices += 400;
    }
  })
//returns me value of each marked checkbox (all of them == 400)
  return extraPrices;
}
//Calculate how much is going to be removed from the final Value
const getDiscountPercent = months => months < 4 ? months * 0.05 : 0.2;
const getTotal = (servicePrice, extraPrice, months) => {

  const getTotal = servicePrice + extraPrice;
  const discountPercent = getDiscountPercent(months);
  
 
  return getTotal - (getTotal * discountPercent);
 
};

//Returns me what's gonna be subtracted from final value
function Total() {
  
  var months = parseInt(document.querySelector('#months').value);
  var finalPrice = (getServicePrice() + extraPrices())*getDiscountPercent(months);
  var totalFinal = (getServicePrice() + extraPrices())- finalPrice ;
  document.getElementById("result").value = "€" + totalFinal ;
}
console.log(totalFinal)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could expand the getDiscountPercent function a bit so it doesn't offer any discount when months input is either not filled or <=0

```
const getDiscountPercent = (months) => {
    // no discount if months are undefined or 0
  let discount = 0
  if (months && months > 0) {
    discount = months < 4 ? months * 0.05 : 0.2;
  }
  return discount
}
```

I've also updated your fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/ke02c51t/2/

Comment: oh feck me, it's a lot clearer now. Believe I was trying to do it the other way around, as in if the discount was 0 else discount = etc etc etc, and it would break all functions so I didn't try to use further, was being a bellend by making things a lot harder than they should, that worked perfectly mate, can't upvote yet but thank you have a good one

Comment: I can relate. Sometimes the mind just goes down a rabbithole :)

Like now when I'm looking at the function I wrote... it could be a bit more elegant.
https://jsfiddle.net/t32eov0b/

Anywho. Glad I could help.